# how to check if current element is the last one when using jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the current element after using jquery each is the last one in the list
i have tried

```
    $('#droplist div.panel').each(function(){
        if($(this).last()){
            alert($(this).attr('id')+' is the last order');
        }else{
            alert('Not the last order');
        }

    });
```

and

```
    $('#droplist div.panel').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':last')){
            alert($(this).attr('id')+' is the last order');
        }else{
            alert('Not the last order');
        }

    });
```

there are a dynamic set of elements, which are being selected, as they are selected I am looping through them and performing calcs as i go along. I need the last one to terminate my calculation functions. ie need to flag that i have reached the last element in the current list.

Thanks all.

Comment: the each callback receive an index argument, try use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($(this).is("#droplist div.panel:last")) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
var panels = $('#droplist div.panel');
var lastpanel = panels.last();
panels.each(function(){
    if($(this).is(lastpanel)){
        alert($(this).attr('id')+' is the last order');
    }else{
        alert('Not the last order');
    }

});
```

Comment: tested the answer above before i saw your answer, sorry. Tested and both ways work ;) thank you so much

Comment: Many ways to skin a cat

Comment: The first option seems a very expensive way of going about it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I came up with the second option, so it wouldn't have to do a search every time through the loop.

Comment: will admit i went with your answer as being cleaner and more inline with my style of coding

Comment: I just wonder which one is less expensive, I still favor performance whenever I can.

Comment: The second method will be less expensive. The first method performs the same search through the DOM to resolve the selector every time through the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the length of the query and compare the current index on the each loop:

```
var list = $('#droplist div.panel')
var length = list.length;
list.each(function(index){
    if(index == length-1){
        alert($(this).attr('id')+' is the last order');
    }else{
        alert('Not the last order');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank You. I did not know about the callback with the returned index.

Comment: will accept as the answer as soon as i can, says i need to wait at least 4 minutes lol ;)

Answer (score 0):

Compare the index and the total number of elements.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gmdt1fd/

Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var objects = $("ul li")
    $.each( objects, function( key, value ) {
        if(key == objects.length-1){
            alert(value+' is the last order');
        }else{
            alert('Not the last order');
        }        
    });


});
```